# The definition of Affine Invariant Riemannian Metric (AIRM)

Tags: matrices, riemannian-geometry

For any two symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrices $A$ and $B$, the Affine Invariant Riemannian Metric (AIRM) between them is defined as [1], [2]:

$d(A,B)=||\log (A^{-1/2}B A^{-1/2}) ||_F$,

where $\log(A)$ is the [matrix logrithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix) of $A$, and $||A||_F$ is the Frobenius norm of $A$.

On the other hand, it is also shown that (e.g., see [3])

$d(A,B)=||\log (A^{-1/2}B A^{-1/2}) ||_F = ||\log (A^{-1}B) ||_F$.

However, when I used Matlab function [logm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logm.html), I found that $||\log (A^{-1/2}B A^{-1/2}) ||_F \ne ||\log (A^{-1}B) ||_F$ at all (but their eigenvalues are the same).

I was wondering if there is anything wrong with my understanding the definition of AIRM?

Thanks very much!

[1] R. Bhatia, Positive Definite Matrices. Princeton University Press, 2009.

[2] X. Pennec, P. Fillard, and N. Ayache, “A Riemannian framework for tensor computing,” International Journal of Computer Vision, vol. 66, no. 1, pp. 41–66, 2006.

[3] M. Moakher, “A differential geometric approach to the geometric mean of symmetric Positive-Definite matrices,” SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl., vol. 26, no. 3, pp. 735–747, 2005.

[4] I. Horev, F. Yger, and M. Sugiyama, “Geometry-aware principal component analysis for symmetric positive definite matrices,” Machine Learning, 2017.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $A, B$ be symmetric positive definite.
Formula (2.9) in [reference [3]](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0895479803436937) reads as follows:
$$
   d(A, B) = \|\mathrm{Log}(A^{-1}B)\|_F = \sqrt{\sum_{i} \log(\lambda_i)^2},
$$
where $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ denote the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}B$.

The right-most side is equal to the left-most side, but the middle part is incorrect, for the following reason (it has little to do with matrix logarithms):

While $A^{-1} B$ indeed has positive eigenvalues, those eigenvalues are in general different from the singular values of $A^{-1} B$. That is because $A^{-1}B$ may be (and usually is) non-symmetric.

The Frobenius norm computes the 2-norm of the vector of singular values, but we need to compute the 2-norm of the vector of eigenvalues. To execute this computation without explicitly computing the eigenvalues, we can observe that $M^2$ is a matrix whose eigenvalues are the squares of the eigenvalues of $M$, and therefore $\mathrm{Tr}(M^2)$ is the sum of squared eigenvalues of $M$---notice that this is different from computing $\mathrm{Tr}(M^\top M) = \|M\|_F^2$ when $M$ is not symmetric.

So we can write the following:
$$
   d(A, B) = \sqrt{\mathrm{Tr}(\mathrm{Log}(A^{-1}B)\mathrm{Log}(A^{-1}B))} = \sqrt{\sum_{i} \log(\lambda_i)^2}.
$$
That it how the formula is [implemented in Manopt](https://github.com/NicolasBoumal/manopt/blob/master/manopt/manifolds/symfixedrank/sympositivedefinitefactory.m).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  If my understanding is correct,  reference [3] used a different definition of the Frobenius norm (instead of singular values, it used eigenvalues of the matrix). That's where the confusion comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. In ref. [3], the Frobenius norm is defined just before eq. (2.1), with the usual definition (they do have the 'transpose' in the definition of the inner product as $\mathrm{Tr}(A^\top B)$). It seems that it's just eq. (2.9) that has this issue as described.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that $\log(A^{-1}B)$ isn't even a symmetric matrix.  Notice that while $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, $A^{-1}B$ isn't necessarily so, even though $A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$ is symmetric positive-definite.  The logarithm likely obscures the way that Matlab computes the Frobenius norm of a matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I agree with you that $A^{-1}B$ is not symmetric, but still, in [3], the author used $||\log(A^{-1}B)||_F$ as AIRM, which is confusing to me.